# FTP script retain timestamp of a file after put

Tags: perl, unix, ftp, timestamp

I know that FTP does not support transferring and retaining file date/time stamps
Wondering if anyone has any ideas/scripts (Shell/perl) that would retain a transfered file's timestamp after a put operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. One option is `rcp -p`. I'm sure some equivalent exists for more secure `scp` as well.
2. As noted by Autocracy, if you can, just tar/zip/otherwise archive the file before transferring and revert back. Unfortunately this doesn't always work - say if you don't have control/acces to the file's source server.
3. Alternately, after "get"-ting the file via FTP, change timestamp to the correct one using Perl's `utime()` or Unix's `touch` command.

   The caveat is if you're *putting* the file onto a remote server, you need to connect (ssh/telnet/rsh) to run the touch command. Kinda cumbersome and not what I'd recommend, but a valid solution even for "put".

Comment: The equivalent option for `scp` is `-p`

Answer (score 2):

Can you perhaps attempt to transfer your files in a tar file? Upon extraction from the .tar, timestamps will be restored.

Comment: Good option but how can you untar via ftp command? 
For example, I only have ftp access to this server

Comment: "site" or "quote" commands may allow you to execute supported system commands. Unfortunately for you, this varies wildly by system. For example, I don't believe proftpd ever allows execution of system software (whereas other FTP systems may use 'ls' to provide ls functions), however it does provide the "SITE UTIME 200412312359 /path/to/some/file.txt" method of changing the timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

[`ncftp`](http://www.ncftp.com/) is the standard upgrade over `/bin/ftp`. Check out `ncftpput`'s `-y`option:

> -y      Try using "SITE UTIME" to preserve timestamps on remote host.  Not many remote FTP servers  support  this, so it may not work.

You might also rest assured knowing `ncftp` works great on a ton of platforms (Windows included)